# C++ Variable mysteriously changed after calling unrelated function

Tags: c++, variables, memory

I have the following code for a board game program that I am making. The function "copyMap" simply copies the contents of the first array map to the second array map_copy. In the function "solver", I have a loop that iterates over the game grid, and for each cell, call copyMap.

The issue is, when solver is called, it runs for 1 iteration then promptly crashes the program. Moreover, the iterators, x_pos and y_pos, which are supposed to start at 0 and 0, gets changed to 2 and 5 after calling copyMap and before the program crashes.

```
void copyMap(int map[][WIDTH], int map_copy[][WIDTH], int rows_to_copy) {
    // copy the contents of the first rows_to_copy rows of map to map_copy
    for( int i = 0 ; i < rows_to_copy ; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < WIDTH ; j++ ) {
            map_copy[i][j] = map[i][j];
            cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int solver(int map[][WIDTH]) {
    int map_copy[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    for(int x_pos = 0 ; x_pos < HEIGHT ; x_pos++ ) {
        for(int y_pos = 0 ; y_pos < WIDTH ; y_pos++ ) {
            copyMap(map, map_copy, MAX_ROWS);
            cout<<x_pos<<" "<<y_pos<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the console output: (For the first iteration of the loop)

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
...
81 8
2 5
```

The game grid has 81 rows and 9 columns, so copyMap prints 0 0, 0 1, ..., 81 8.
Then, solver prints 2 5. However, the iterators are still supposed to be 0 0.
The iterators are not passed to the function copyMap at all. Why are their values being changed, and why is my program crashing?

I would appreciate any help on this issue, thank you.

Comment: Aside: It seems odd that you have a nested loop but you don't use either loop variant in the body (except for the `cout`). --- How do you call `solver()`?

Comment: Most likely you have UB in your code. You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: Random guess: is `MAX_ROWS` larger than `HEIGHT`?

Comment: You could run your program under a debugger and put a memory watch on the address of `x_pos` or `y_pos`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I stripped away the rest of the code to narrow down on the problem. `solver()` is called from another function that handles the user input which passes an array `map[9][9]` defined in `main()` to `solver()`

Comment: @super sorry, what is a UB?

Comment: And does `MAX_ROWS` equal 9?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError nope, HEIGHT and WIDTH is 9 and MAX_ROWS is 81.

Comment: @Imperator1550 Undefined behaviour. It happens when you break the rules of the language by doing things that are not allowed. In this case, going out-of-bounds of the array or failing to initialize the arrays properly in the first case are the main 2 things to look for. Hence, you need to show a [mcve].

Comment: And why do you try to copy `81` rows when your array only has `9` rows?

Comment: Similar issue we had in a Delphi program, there was an ex-C guy, who inserted `strcopy` everywhere instead of Delphi native strings, and since he did not trust libraries he always manually put `\0` into the last `char[]` slot. After moving to Unicode his pointer/index maths went wrong and started bombing zeroes into twice the real array length. It ended with "mysterious" bug i was finally called to help find. It looked just the same, you call a function and a local variable suddenly changes. The guy was VERY reluctant to go into that inner funciton call, "there can be nothing there,variable is

Comment: ...the variable is local and can not be accesses. Despite debugger was saying it did. When i finally foced him to do we dived into 5 (five!) function calls and on the 5-th level of "recursion" we finally met this C-strings based bomber, which precisiously nuked the local variable of a function 5 levels above in call stack. // So what you have to do i believe is: make a GLOBAL pointer to the variable suddenly changing, assign that pointer in the function, put the value pointed at into watch screen of your debugger, and then go inner calls until you found the moment it changes for real

Answer (score 0):

Copymap iterates through each element. I don't think you need to call it inside a nested loop inside solver. You should take it outside of the loop and set a breakpoint inside the loop to watch x_pos and y_pos.

Comment: And how does this answer the question `Why are their values being changed, and why is my program crashing?`?

Comment: Maybe not a direct answer but I'm saying how to debug it. Also take a look at nested loop. Map is being copied twice.

Comment: Actually, `solver()` needs to copy the map for each cell and do some work on the map_copy for each cell and find out the best move.
But anyway I found out the problem: map has 81 rows and 9 columns but map_copy has 9 rows and 9 columns, so I guess `copyMap()` tried to access some out-of-bounds memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, turns out map has 81 rows and 9 columns but map_copy only has 9 rows and 9 columns, so copyMap tried to access out-of-bounds memory locations.